# Mudar abas através do Modal bootstrap

Tags: jquery

Graças ao nosso colega DontVoteMeDown, consigo mudar as abas através de botões por essa solução [abas com jquery](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). Porém quando tento mudar as abas pelo modal do Bootstrap, não consigo. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    $("#Sim").on("click", function() 
            {
          $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
          var indice = $('#tabs ul li a[href="#' + $(this).parent().prop("id") + '"]').parent().index();
          $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", (indice + 1));
    });
```

`("#Sim")` é o Id do botão, ou seja, pelo Modal pergunto se ele quer cadastrar mais um serviço, se ele clicar em Sim, era para ir para outra aba:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Sim" data-dismiss="modal">Sim</button>
```

Comment: como você já está usando o Bootstrap poderia usar as [abas desse framework](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Comment: @Jose.Marcos, crie um teste para podermos entender melhor o que você precisa: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. A solução foi a seguinte. A estrutura das abas está da seguinte forma:

```
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Aba 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Aba 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aba 3</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Aba 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Quando clico no botão **Sim** coloquei o seguinte código:

```
 $("#Sim").on("click", function() 
            {  
        var novaURL = "index.php?#tabs-2";
        $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);    
});
```

Observem que coloquei o **#tabs-2** referente a **Aba 2** e assim por diante.
    .....